# How to set a link in Google Apps Script HTMLService? (error the conexion with accounts.google.com recused)

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-apps-script-editor

I'm tring to use the Apps Script method `setContent()` to add a link do a simple `index.html` file in Google Apps Script.

```
  var newDocLink = "https://docs.google.com/document/d/1loBt7T7-4qd0ORBXiTFeDQxuG..."; 
  // newDocLink variable have some Google Docs URL as value
  var output = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('Click <a href= " '  + newDocLink + ' ">here to open the link in a new tab</a> a minuta')
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(output, 'My page title');
```

I get the link, but when I click on it,  it doesn't work, showing this message "the conexion with accounts.google.com recused", in my language.

I know this is very simple, but I know very little of HTML and, after looking for similar questions, didn't find a solution or similar purpose code. Any help would be appreciate!

Comment: Have you added text between the anchor tags? Note that creating the `HtmlOutput` from a file is unnecessary if you're just going to call `setContent`

Comment: Hi, thank you very much, @tehhowch . The text between the anchor tags is the URL converted in a string

Comment: @tehhowch, I changed the code, but I still have a error "the conexion with accounts.google.com recused". Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Issue:

- You're trying to open a Google document inside a iframe, which Google docs doesn't allow.

#### Solution:

- Open it in a new tab by setting `target` attribute

  ```
  var output = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('Click <a rel="noreferrer noopener" href= " '  + newDocLink + ' " target="_blank">here to open the link in a new tab</a>')
  ```

#### References:

- [Anchor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a)